# SQL Average Multiple Columns

Tags: php, sql, average, rows

How would you go about working out the average of multiple columns and rows?

My code so far is:

```
SELECT b.id, r.id, b.name, r.business_id, (r.service + r.value + r.quality) / 3 AS average 
                        FROM business b
                        LEFT JOIN rating r ON r.business_id = b.id
```

[image]

I'd like to get the average of r.service, r.value and r.quality and combine the business_id column.

So I should get:
business_id = average: 9.42 (for example)

Comment: I suggest looking into [Aggregate Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

Comment: so in the example that you gave, you want to have the average for  business_id (so ill end up with only one column for business_id 1 with average 8.83335 )

Comment: Where does 9.42 come from?

Comment: 9.42 is just a random number sorry - What I'm after is to get the combine average for each business ID

Comment: @Argod that's correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aggregate function AVG should take an expression for aggregation, so this should work:

```
SELECT b.name, r.business_id, AVG((r.service + r.value + r.quality)/3)
FROM business b
    LEFT JOIN rating r ON r.business_id = b.id
GROUP BY b.name, r.business_id
LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: Looks hopefully but I get the following:  #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Can you try it now - I edited it so that the commas were replaced with + signs in `AVG()` (I'm sure that's what the original answerer meant).

Comment: Ah! Works perfectly now! I've added AS average at the end of the AVG so I can order by the average. Thanks @DavidFaber!